# Docker and rancher

Tags: bash, docker, rancher

i never really understood how to start a docker and how to maintain it alive.

I have a question, so when you start a docker in the terminal you must provide a command for the docker so it maintains alive, and when you dont provide a service it restarts everytime, you can provide the /bin/bash so it maintains open. (Could you show me how to do it the right way, maintain it open with bash ?)

When it comes to rancher, when you create a new docker you can provide the command too, but if you dont the docker won't restart it maintains alive, so what does this means, that it have default command ? (/bin/bash)? What command does exactly executes rancher to start the docker?

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best if you read some about docker, to get the various concepts clear. From your use of "a docker", it seems that you don't really have all the pieces yet for an easy understanding.

A quick layout would be that you have

- Image. I have seen this compared to a 'class' in programming
- Container. In the same comparison, this would be an object: an instance of a class.

If you want to run something with docker, you start a container from an image. Just like if you want to create an object, you create one from a class. (lets not take this comparison/simili too far)

Now a containers purpose is to run something, rather, to run a single something. So "keeping a docker open" is not something you 'should want' What you want is to run, for instance, a server. Or a script.

Every container runs a single process (or should run one). As the 'official' usecase is not 'create a virtual server you can play around', it might behave strange or complicated if you want to have place to ssh to and not run a specific thing.

This also means you don't want to run any services as a background: if you run apache, you want to run it not as a daemon, but just run it: that's what the docker container is for. If you need to run something else (for instance, a database server) you would start a second container.

There might be exceptions for this, but to get your head around the why stuff works as it does, you should probably start somewhat religiously with these 'rules', and from that point go on.